# Is there a way to call a function every time a module is required in Lua 5.1?

Tags: lua, dsl

For example, to change the requiring file's environment? In my case, I'm creating a DSL (Domain Specific Language) for building behavior trees, and it would be nice if I could do something like this:

```
require "behaviortree"

return Sequence {
    -- definition of tree
}
```

without polluting the global namespace with node names, or using a construct like

```
require "behaviortree".init()
```

because that's kinda ugly in my opinion. Simply placing a setfenv call in the module file's body doesn't do what I want because it would only call when I require the module the first time and not every time because of require's module caching.

I thought about clearing out the cache of the module every time I require it, but that would mean I need to do something like

```
require "behaviortrees"

local tree = Sequence {
    -- definition of tree
}

create(tree)
```

and clear the module cache in the create function. That is also something I would like to avoid, but is a better option than calling an init function of the module.

Is there any 'clean' way of using a module to set the environment of the requiring file?

Comment: You could `dofile` instead of `require`.  This doesn't cache at all but only works with Lua modules.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, I didn't think of that. But I would really really like to keep the require "behaviortrees" line, for purely aesthetic purposes, if at all possible.

Comment: Modules that `return false` are not cached, and are reloaded on every `require`-call.

Comment: @siffiejoe That actually does exactly what I want it to! Thanks a ton. I would accept this if it weren't a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own `require` function that loads the module using the "original" require and then calls the `init` function you need on it. Even though the "original" require returns the cached version, your own `require` function will still call the `init` function.